# Mediawiki API Sandbox - get all translation alternatives

Tags: wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikimedia

I wish to retrive with wikimedia api (here it is the [Sandbox](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox)) all translation versions of a page.
As an example, in this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:1935_births I need to retrive all links that are on the left sidebar after the Language title.
Is there a way? I'm trying in different ways but I'm not able to succeed.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I get the way

https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&&titles=Category:London&prop=langlinks&lllimit=500&format=xml&rawcontinue

Thank you the same!